# Python NLTK Remove Internal Punctuation NOT Part of a URL

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using NLTK in Python, and I'm having an issue with trying to remove internal punctuation from text where there is supposed to be a space after the period to start a new sentence.

Here are a few examples:

'on.How'

'time.Jerry'

'me?What'

How can I remove the punctuation from the preceding examples, but still keep punctuation in URLs like stackoverflow.com or nltk.org?

Thanks!

Comment: show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can extract URLs by using [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizers). Then you can take URLs in a list and using simple python you can do your job. Let's take we took URL in a list called URL...

```
sentence = "hi.hello.stackoverflow.com or nltk.org"
URL = ["stackoverflow.com", "nltk.org"]

# to remove URLs from our sentence and place a number so we can later replace 
# our URLs there
x=0
for i in URL:
    sentence = sentence.replace(i,str(x))
    x+=1

# put period with space
sentence=sentence.split(".")
sentence = ". ".join(sentence)

# replace our URLs in the correct place
x=0
for i in URL:
    sentence = sentence.replace(str(x),i)
    x+=1
print(sentence)
# output - "hi. hello. stackoverflow.com or nltk.org"
```